# Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженным указательным местоимением

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли здесь тире после слова "деталь"? В интернете не нашла, но тире (слово "это") здесь просится.

Надежнейшая деталь та, которой нет.

Также и здесь:

Гусеницы (-) такое же  оружие танка, как и его орудие.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во втором точно нужно. В первом... Да и в первом тоже.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Но в первом, значит, необязательно?

Comment: _Однажды он мне как-то сказал: "Юрий Петрович, в танке самая лучшая деталь та, которой нет. Ее не надо изготавливать, за ней не надо ухаживать в эксплуатации, она никогда не сломается"._ === **§ 5…** Если сказуемое выражено прилагательным (в том числе местоименным)… тире перед сказуемым **обычно** не ставится…
(http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92,7#pp92 ) === Но **при логическом или интонационном членении предложения** может быть поставлено.

Comment: _Alenka: Но в первом, значит, [тире] необязательно?_ === Не обязательно. Но можно  и поставить. Справочное бюро Грамоты.ру на вопрос, нужно ли тире перед "именно" в предложении _"Наша компания именно та, которая предлагает..."_ ответило так:  
_По основному правилу тире не требуется. Однако можно поставить интонационное тире._

Answer (score 2):

1) Надежнейшая деталь тА, которой нет. Тире не ставится.

Называется признак, поэтому акцентируется указательное местоимение, паузы нет

Сравнить: "Высшая форма тА, которая богаче свободой".

Пример с тире: Но есть высшая форма - та, которая богаче свободой (присоединительная конструкция).

2) Гусеницы - такое же оружие танка, как и его орудие.

Обозначено тождество: гусеница - это оружие, тире ставится в обязательнои порядке

Comment: _Vera: "Называется признак, поэтому акцентируется указательное местоимение, паузы нет"._ === **Vera**, ну почему Вы за автора-то решаете, есть ли у него пауза или нет? === Вы приводите пример: _"Высшая форма тА, которая богаче свободой"._ Ну и? Аналогичные Вашему примеры-то ведь можно подобрать и с тире: "Точное применение дарвиновского критерия (**высшая форма — та, которая** пережила другую в борьбе за существование) тотчас обнаруживает всю относительность его". === По-моему, чтобы принимать решение по постановке / непостановке тире в таких предложениях, нужно (как минимум!) знать контекст..

Comment: Ситуация 1. Какую деталь называют надежнейшей? Надежнейшая деталь тА, которой нет. Ситуация 2.  Вы, наверное, слышали выражение "надежнейшая деталь". Что же такое "надежнейшая деталь" (даем определение). Надежнейшая деталь  -  (это) та, которой нет.  Комментарий. Скорее всего, мы имеем дело с ситуацией №1, когда определяется признак (вероятность 99%). Но ситуация №2 тоже возможна (1%).